# How to improve the efficiency of the script?

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I have two files, one has 4K strings to be 4K rows, one has 100K to be 100K rows.

For each string in the 4k rows, I calculated the similarity ratio between the string and each string in the 100k string, and I pick the string in the 100k rows with the highest similarity ratio as a "match" to the row in the 4k file.

I tried to finish the job using the python dictionary. I was told it would be efficient.

But my code is not efficient, see the following:

```
for k,k2 in itertools.product(dict1.keys(),my_dict1.keys()):
   a=float(difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,k,k2).ratio())
     if a>0.80:
         my_dict3[k+"t"+k2]=a


for key2 in my_dict3.keys():
        k1=key2.split("t")[0]
        k2=key2.split("t")[1]
        mydict[k1][k2]=my_dict3[key2]
        k=key2.split("t")

keylist4=mydict.keys()

for key4 in keylist4:
        key=max(mydict[key4].iteritems(),key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
        print "%st%s" % (key4,key)
```

I am wondering why the code is not efficient. But it should be. How to improve?

I think I did something wrong, but not sure where.

Thank you!

Comment: Because you are iterating over `100K * 4k = 400M` combinations?

Comment: yes, how to avoid this by using dictionary of python?

Comment: I don;t think that is possible, you **do** have to iterate over *all* the combinations of the keys, don't you?

Comment: yes, but someone said we could get a much higher speed by using dictionary of python.

Comment: I do not know how to utilize the python dictionary to speed up the script.

Comment: I added the algorithm tag beacuse this is more about better algo than python optimization

Comment: What kind of strings do you have? Real words or id that are of the same length or arbitrary letter combos? I'm asking because, as mu points out, you will need to reduce the combinations. Nearest-neighbour-search strategies might be useful. For example, the strings with the best similarity will be of a sililar length.

Comment: They are the names of some tv series and movies, like "24 season 1 3:00pm-4:00pm"

Comment: `difflib.SequenceMatcher` uses the Ratcliff-Obershelp algorithm for pattern matching, which is based on recursively finding longest common substring. There might be something there, but I couldn't find anything to significantly improve performance.

Comment: Later on a friend of mine used R to code. And the R script is efficient. It takes R 20-30 mins to finish the job. So 400M calculation is not s problem for a computer. I guess my code is too inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Though this particular piece of code can be slightly optimized, the time complexity will still remain `O(m*n)`, where `m`, `n` are the number of keys in each dict.

Since dict_1 has `4K` keys, and `dict_2` has 100K keys, total combinations to iterate over

```
100K*4K = 400M
```

If for each combination it took you `0.1 ms` to figure stuff out, time still needed  to completely run this program

```
400M/(10000*86400) = 472 days = 1.4 years
```

Even if you are able to improve the performance by `20%`, you will still take `1.4*0.8 = 1.1 year`.

Even if you uses 10 simultaneous threads to do this, you would need a month and a half to run this.

So, it is best to figure out another algorithmic solution to this problem of yours, which performs better in terms of time complexity.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much. I know what you mean.

Comment: @user3634601 Hey, if your query was resolved, don't forget to [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), or post one which worked for you :)